# Why isn't this code running after this line?

Tags: python

I have an issue where after I defined all the student's and go to add grades. It doesn't give me an error but, just ends the code there instead.

Where the code breaks:

```
def particular_class():
  sname = input("Students name?: ")
  for students in Students:
    if (students == sname):
      print("""
      1. Math
      2. English
      3. Comp Sci 
      4. Science
      5. History
      6. French
      7. Quit""")
      grade = int(input("What subject would you like to input a grade for?\n"))
      if grade == 1:
        Math.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 2:
        English.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 3:
        Comp_sci.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 4:
        Science.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 5:
        History.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 6:
        French.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 7:
        Choice()
```

[image of how the code breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjYwq.png)

The entire code:

```
Students = {}
Stud = {}
Kids = []
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
      self.classes = []
      self.name = input("What is the name of the student?\n")
      Done = True
      while(Done):
        grade = int(input("Please Enter a grade between 9 - 12\n"))
        if grade < 9:
          print()
        elif grade > 12:
          print()
        else:
          Done = False
      self.age = int(input("What is the age of the student?\n"))
      Stud[self.name] = "Grade", grade, "Age", self.age
      self.grade_storage = {}
      self.Total_grades = []
      self.Class_Average = {}
      self.Average = []
      global av
      av = 0

    def Add_students(s):
      Students[s.name] = s
      print()
      print(Stud)
      print("Students in your class:", len(Students))
      Choice()

    def Add_grades(self, student):
      global av
      Assignment = input("Name of Assignment?\n")
      Grade = int(input("Grade for Assignement?\n"))
      student.Total_grades.append(Grade)
      student.Class_Average[Assignment] = Grade
      Num_of_Assignments = len(student.Class_Average)
      total = sum(student.Total_grades)
      student.Average = total/Num_of_Assignments
      av = round(student.Average, 2)
      Choice()

    def assignments(self, student):
      print(student.Class_Average)
      Choice()

    def GPA(self, student):
      print("Average", student.Average)
      avg = av * 100
      int(avg)
      y = 0
      for x in range(0, int(avg)):
        y += 0.04
      z = y/100
      c = round(z,2)
      print("GPA:", c)

class Genesis:
  def Remove_students(self):
    name = input("What is the name of the student?\n")
    del Students[name]
    print(Students)
    print("Students in your class:", len(Students))
    Choice() 

  def Students(self):
      print()
      Kids.sort()
      for Studs in Kids:
        print(Studs)
      print("Students in your class:", len(Students))
      Choice()

print("You require a minimum of 6 students to have a class, please add your students:")
Math = Student()
English = Student()
Science = Student()
History = Student()
French = Student()
Comp_sci = Student()

def assignments():
  sname = input("Students name?: ")
  for students in Students:
    if (students == sname):
      print("""
      1. Math
      2. English
      3. Comp Sci 
      4. Science
      5. History
      6. French
      7. Quit""")
      grade = int(input("What subject would you like to see assignments for?\n"))
      if grade == 1:
        Math.assignments(Students[students])
      elif grade == 2:
        English.assignments(Students[students])
      elif grade == 3:
        Comp_sci.assignments(Students[students])
      elif grade == 4:
        Science.assignments(Students[students])
      elif grade == 5:
        History.assignments(Students[students])
      elif grade == 6:
        French.assignments(Students[students])
      elif grade == 7:
        Choice()

def particular_class():
  sname = input("Students name?: ")
  for students in Students:
    if (students == sname):
      print("""
      1. Math
      2. English
      3. Comp Sci 
      4. Science
      5. History
      6. French
      7. Quit""")
      grade = int(input("What subject would you like to input a grade for?\n"))
      if grade == 1:
        Math.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 2:
        English.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 3:
        Comp_sci.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 4:
        Science.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 5:
        History.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 6:
        French.Add_grades(Students[students])
      elif grade == 7:
        Choice()

def Choice():
  print("""1. Add Students
2. Add Grades
3. View Grade
4. Remove Student
5. View Students
6. GPA\n""")
  Attendance = Genesis()
  Option = int(input("Please choice an option.\n"))
  if Option == 1:
    global s
    s = Student()
    Student.Add_students(s)
  elif Option == 2:
    particular_class()
  elif Option == 3:
    assignments()
  elif Option == 4: 
    Attendance.Remove_students()
  elif Option == 5:
    Attendance.Students()
  elif Option == 6:
    print()
Choice()
```

Comment: *"just ends the code there instead."* What do you mean by "ends", how have you determined that it "ends", and where specifically does it "end"? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] with full information about the inputs, expected result, actual result, and what you've done to try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your design. If `Student` represents a student, why do you do things like `Math = Student()`? Is there only one student in each subject?

Comment: There's no need to loop through a dictionary to find the student that was named, just use `student = Students[sname]`

Comment: My design is currently a little bit messed up, I did ```Math = Student()``` in order to show the different classes and to differentiate them.

Comment: You should have a different class for subjects, don't use the same `Student` class for that.

Comment: Don't use a recursive call to `Choice()` in place of a loop.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way out of the recursion. If you select Quit it goes back to `Choice()`, it doesn't quit.

Answer (score 0):

Because there isn't students with given name and then there is no call to Choice, Exception or anything. I would advise making menus with `while True:` and not recursive calls each time. You will stack overflow pretty quick with your approach.